# why I get "NA" as a result of min() and max() in my dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, max, min

I have a dataframe(mydat) that has no any missing data.

I use below commands:

```
min(mydat)

max(mydat)
```

for achieving the minimum and maximum values of my dataframe but for both the above functions, I get

> NA

as a result in the console.

Now, I really confused and I don't know why I get that result.
I appreciate if anybody shares his/her comment with me.

Comment: Try `min(mydat, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: `sapply(mydat, anyNA)` might help

Comment: Without seeing any of your data, all we can do is guess, which ultimately isn't very helpful for you or future SO users. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have NA in your data. If that isn't expected then you should investigate. If that is expected and if you want the min/max ignoring the NA values use the na.rm=TRUE parameter like

```
min(mydat, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks@Dason. also my guess was as your answer. So, I run below code:           
 `which(datExprRCT=="NA", arr.ind = TRUE)` but I couldnt find any missing value. could you please give me code for finding "NA" in mydat and remove it?

Comment: Use is.na(yourdata). If you try direct comparison against a string containing "NA" it won't get you anywhere. @Mohammad

Comment: ok@Dason. I found some missing values in "mydata". could you please tell me by which command I can find their indexes in "mydata"? because I have to replace a value instead of them.